# how to link pug links with href

Tags: pug

How does one create pug links in a nav for example. If I have say three pages, index, page1 and page2, and I have li links in a ul like the following:

```
ul
  li
    a(href="/index") Home
  li
    a(href="/page1") Page1
  li
    a(href="/page3") Page2
```

I have uses slashes as absolute url's, is this the right way to do it?

thanks

Comment: It depends on where those pages exist. But generally, links in Pug work the same way the do in regular HTML.

Comment: They are all in the same level. So, is the above correctly coded then? And I dont need to put the file extension, like:  a(href="/page1.pug") Page1

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see?

Comment: Well, I did try it, I am using parcel and if I click one of the above links, page2, it shows the page2 in the url, but it is still the index page that is displayed. Maybe this is a parcel issue rather then a pug issue. But I wanted to exclude all possible reasons for the behavior.